# How to set Run Configuration and Debug Configuration in Eclipse to choose the class that has the main method as the start-up class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for Java EE, Mars 2.

I have two classes in my Java (Swing application) project:

1. Program.java (has the main method)
2. Foo.java

If I right-click the editor while `Program.java` is open, the context-menu presents the commands **Java Application** and **Run Configurations** under the **Run As** menu.

The same happens if I right-click the editor surface while `Program.java` is open and choose **Debug As** from the context-menu. I see the two sub-menu items namely, **Java Application** and **Debug Configurations**.

However, when I have `Foo.java` open, right-clicking the editor surface presents only one sub-menu item named **Run Configurations** or **Debug Configurations** upon choosing **Run As** or **Debug As** respectively.

So, every time I want to run my project and I accidentally right-click the editor surface area while `Foo.java` is open, I then have to go to the editor tab that has `Program.java` open and right-click again and choose the right menu item.

I am suspecting there is a way in the **Run Configurations** and **Debug Configurations** dialog boxes to tell Eclipse to choose the `Program.java` class to run as the start-up class since it has the `main` method.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn to "Project->Properties" and then select "Run/Debug Settings". There you should be able to configure your project so that it always "runs" the same.

Alternatively, some workaround that I often use when doing JUnit testing on different classes: on top of your eclipse window, there are these buttons

[image: screenshot]

The pulldown icon there opens a "history" of your last run/debug/... "runs". So, once you got your program "run"; you can just use that history to invoke it.

Comment: I looked up the `Project -> Properties -> Run/Debug Settings` and apparently, they were already rightly configured to load up `Program.java` as the *main* class. Still, I deleted that configuration and created it anew. However, there's no change to the behavior I described. It looks like there might not be a solution to this. That history thing is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Foo.java and in **Run Configurations** dialog, add main class, like below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution is setting your launching configuration in window -> preferences 
and you can run your project using F11 key (or any key that you can config) i[image: window -> preference]